# Python -- Search Subsrtring Full Word(s)

Tags: python, string, algorithm, python-2.7, substring

I want to find the number of times a substring occurred in a string. I was doing this

```
termCount = content.count(term)
```

But if i search like "Ford" it returned result set like

```
"Ford Motors"         Result: 1 Correct
"cannot afford Ford"  Result: 2 Incorrect
"ford is good"        Result: 1 Correct
```

The search term can have multiple terms like "Ford Motors" or "Ford Auto".
For example if i search "Ford Motor"

```
"Ford Motors"               Result: 1 Correct
"cannot afford Ford Motor"  Result: 1 Correct
"Ford Motorway"             Result: 1 InCorrect
```

What i want is to search them case insensitive and as a whole. Mean if I search a substring it should be contained as a whole as a word or a phrase (In case of multiple terms) not part of the word. And also I need the count of the terms. How do I achieve it.

Comment: what about the `s` in end of `"Ford Motors"`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem `'cannot afford Ford'.count('Ford')` -> `1` (not `2`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regex`, and in this case use `re.findall` then get the length of matched list :

```
re.findall(r'\byour_term\b',s)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sG5sM5/1)

```
>>> s="Ford Motors cannot afford Ford Motor Ford Motorway Ford Motor."
>>> import re
>>> def counter(str,term):
...    return len(re.findall(r'\b{}\b'.format(term),str))
... 
>>> counter(s,'Ford Motor')
2
>>> counter(s,'Ford')
4
>>> counter(s,'Fords')
0
```

Comment: I cannot do that because it will search after splitting it on space and search term can have multiple terms.

Comment: @planet260 can you add an example to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I would split the strings by spaces so that we have independent words and then from there I would carry out the count.

```
terms = ['Ford Motors', 'cannot afford Ford', 'ford is good'];
splitWords = [];

for term in terms:
    #take each string in the list and split it into words
    #then add these words to a list called splitWords.

    splitWords.extend(term.lower().split())

print(splitWords.count("ford"))
```